# htaccess' rewrite rule keeps redirecting to old domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I had the following code in my htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/
```

The main idea was to remove the "www" from the URL because it was giving problems with Facebook apps, but now the domain has changed, so I updated the htaccess, but it keeps redirecting to that old domain, I know that some browsers keep as cache the redirects, so, is there a way to tell the browser to grab this new redirect condition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser's cache and try this :

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: is there a way to do it, but without clearing the cache?